Virt-Manager Closes VM Automatically When Switching Desktops
OS: Linux - Fedora 41
Applications: KVM/QEMU under Virt-Manager
Whenever I'm running virt-manager and have a vm running and I switch to a different virtual desktop on my host os for awhile the vm running in virt-manager stops and closes. I have to re-run the vm again to have it activate. I'm not sure what's going on and why this keeps happening. Nothing in my power management settings seem to be contributing to the issue.
Any ideas?
It makes it difficult to do work on a vm if it automatically closes when I switch over to another virtual desktop.
All suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.
